# How can I do less than, greater than in JSON array object Postgres fields?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-10

I want to retrieve data by specific field operation it store array of object. i want to add new object in it.

```
CREATE TABLE justjson ( id INTEGER, doc JSONB);
INSERT INTO justjson VALUES ( 1, '[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "age": "22"
  },
  {
    "name": "def",
    "age": "23"
  }
]');
```

retrieve data where age is greater then and equal to 23 how is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eg [using](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) `jsonb_array_elements`:

```
t=# with a as (select *,jsonb_array_elements(doc) k from justjson)
select k from a where (k->>'age')::int >= 23;
              k
------------------------------
 {"age": "23", "name": "def"}
(1 row)
```

Comment: This solutions i am already try but i have billion of records that decrease performance.
is any alternative solutions

Comment: I'm just answering your question. If you want to ask for more performant solution, please post another question